# Confusion on what pixel size to set in new image set

Tags: ios, xcode, resolution, asset-catalog

In Images.xcassets under New Image Set i'm going to use device specific to get the same image for different sizes. I'll be using iPhone 2x, Retina 4 2x, 3x and iPad 1x, 2x. If for iPhone 6+ I want to make an image 40x40 Pixels @3x and for iPhone 6 I want to make the image 30x30 pixels @2x, am I not allowed to do that, is the image supposed to be only 20x20 for 2x? Can I just put both images for example 50x50 one in 2x and other in 3x or is this not allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images have to be exactly the right size, you can't give it any other size.

So `30x30@2x` must be a `60px` by `60px` png file, and `40x40@3x` must be `120px` by `120px`. You multiply the width/height by 2x, and the same for 3x.

Comment: So if i make a 60x60 image for 3x, can i manually make the UIImageView smaller in storyboard, or am i not even allowed to do that and must keep the 60x60 size for iPhone 6+ for example because it  won't recognize image if it's not 60x60?

Comment: If your image view is 60x60 points, then you must create a 60x60px image, a 120x120px image and a 180x180px image. You can give an image view any size image, but it will look wrong and might even get your app rejected by app review (depending where the image is used).

Comment: Last question. I have 40 images at 2x. Does this mean now i have to create  40 new images for 3x iPhone,  and 40 new images for 1x iPad and 40 new images for 2x iPad. Total of 120 new images? Doesn't it take too much MB?

Comment: Yep, you need to create a lot of images and yes it does take up a lot of space. You can use the `sips` command line tool in Terminal.app (see `man sips`) or photoshop to create all the images.

Comment: But you can't resize your 2x images up to 3x. That will be horrible. You're going to have to re-create them at 3x and then resize down to 2x and 1x.